# Parse JSON in python problem with syntax with square brackets

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON received from an API where is A word definition from English Dictionary. I need to parse the data and separate meanings, definitions, and examples but I have some syntax problems with the JSON file.

Here is an example received JSON for the word Handsome:

```
[   
  {
    "word": "handsome",
    "phonetic": "/ˈhæn.səm/",
    "phonetics": [
      {
        "text": "/ˈhæn.səm/",
        "audio": "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-uk.mp3",
        "sourceUrl": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9021972",
        "license": {
          "name": "BY 3.0 US",
          "url": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us"
        }
      },
      {
        "text": "/ˈhæn.səm/",
        "audio": "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-us.mp3",
        "sourceUrl": "https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1648256",
        "license": {
          "name": "BY-SA 3.0",
          "url": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "meanings": [
      {
        "partOfSpeech": "verb",
        "definitions": [
          {
            "definition": "To render handsome.",
            "synonyms": [],
            "antonyms": []
          }
        ],
        "synonyms": [],
        "antonyms": []
      },
      {
        "partOfSpeech": "adjective",
        "definitions": [
          {
            "definition": "(of people, things, etc) Having a good appearance; good-looking.",
            "synonyms": [],
            "antonyms": [],
            "example": "a handsome garment, house, tree, or horse"
          },
          {
            "definition": "Good, appealing, appropriate.",
            "synonyms": [],
            "antonyms": []
          },
          {
            "definition": "Generous or noble in character.",
            "synonyms": [],
            "antonyms": [],
            "example": "Handsome is as handsome does."
          },
          {
            "definition": "Ample; moderately large.",
            "synonyms": [],
            "antonyms": [],
            "example": "a handsome salary"
          },
          {
            "definition": "(said of things and people) Dexterous; skillful.",
            "synonyms": [],
            "antonyms": []
          }
        ],
        "synonyms": [
          "hefty",
          "substantial",
          "good-looking",
          "pretty"
        ],
        "antonyms": []
      }
    ],
    "license": {
      "name": "CC BY-SA 3.0",
      "url": "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"
    },
    "sourceUrls": [
      "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handsome"
    ]   
   } 
 ]
```

I wrote this code to load data and parse the data I want:

```
data = [{"word":"handsome","phonetic":"/ˈhæn.səm/","phonetics":[{"text":"/ˈhæn.səm/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-uk.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9021972","license":{"name":"BY 3.0 US","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us"}},{"text":"/ˈhæn.səm/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-us.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1648256","license":{"name":"BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"}}],"meanings":[{"partOfSpeech":"verb","definitions":[{"definition":"To render handsome.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"partOfSpeech":"adjective","definitions":[{"definition":"(of people, things, etc) Having a good appearance; good-looking.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"a handsome garment, house, tree, or horse"},{"definition":"Good, appealing, appropriate.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"Generous or noble in character.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Handsome is as handsome does."},{"definition":"Ample; moderately large.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"a handsome salary"},{"definition":"(said of things and people) Dexterous; skillful.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":["hefty","substantial","good-looking","pretty"],"antonyms":[]}],"license":{"name":"CC BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"},"sourceUrls":["https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handsome"]}]
json_load = (json.loads(json_data))
print(json_load['meanings'])
```

this error is shown: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
. If I add `[0]` to before `[meanings]` the problem is solved but I don't know why should I do that: `print(json_load[0]['meanings'])`

Also, I have the same problem for the inner levels and I cannot parse the data. If I remove the square brackets from the beginning and end of the JSON string, there is no more need for `[0]` before `[meanings]`.

What should I do? Do I need to add numbers before keys or do I have to remove square brackets for all levels?

Comment: Btw, this format is called JSONL (JSON list), which is a list of JSON objects.

Comment: You have `data` not `json_data`, also data is a list which contains a dictionary

Comment: `.loads` means *load string* (for str, bytes or bytearray instead of a file object)

Comment: Even changing data with json_data you code doesn't work for the reason I mentioned, so you should post the code AS IS, to avoid copypaste error and for peaople to reproduce your error.

Comment: @DeadlyPointer No it's not. JSONL is short for JSON Lines, containing *newline* separated objects. Also the JSON term for a list is "array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API response is wrapped in a list, presumably because it could have returned multiple results.

So yeah, you would "add numbers before keys" (i.e. access the zeroth member of the array); I'd just guard against unexpectedly getting multiple results, and then grab the zeroth one and work on that.

```
parsed_data = json.loads(json_data)
if len(parsed_data) != 1:
    raise ValueError(f"Oops, got {len(parsed_data)} results!")
first_definition = parsed_data[0]

print(first_definition["word"], "(", first_definition["phonetic"], ")")

for meaning in first_definition["meanings"]:
    print("*", meaning["partOfSpeech"])
    for defn in meaning["definitions"]:
        print("  *", defn["definition"])
    # ... etc...
```

Comment: Some KEYs are only in one lit. For this word key "example" is only in the second "meaning" and not in the first one. While I am trying to parse data using for loop I face an error parsing the KEY. How can I parse data of example from second meaning?

Comment: `if "example" in meaning:`, or e.g. `ex = meaning.get("example")` (so `ex` becomes either the example or `None`).

Answer (score 0):

`{` and `[` are separate brackets. The first means "here follows an 'object'" whereas the second means "here follows a list". Therefore, if you paste the raw data that you got from the API

```
[
  {
    "word":"handsome",
    "phonetic":"/ˈhæn.səm/",
    "phonetics": [
      {
        "text":"/ˈhæn.səm/",
      
  "audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-uk.mp3",
        "sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9021972","license":{"name":"BY 3.0 US",
...
```

You have a list, containing an object (or potentially multiple). So the best thing to do is indeed use the numerical index `0` to get the first object in the list. Or even better, first check how many objects are in the list with `len(json_load)`.

Answer (score 0):

the error you get means that you are trying to access a list item using a string key (wich is impossible, you can access lists using int index only).

- you need to access the list first then you can access the inner json key value pairs
- same for any inner lists inside the json you need to specify the index first then you can access the data

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting those data from some API then it's likely that you're getting them as a string. So let's make your data into a string like this:

```
js = '''[{"word":"handsome","phonetic":"/ˈhæn.səm/","phonetics":[{"text":"/ˈhæn.səm/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-uk.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9021972","license":{"name":"BY 3.0 US","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us"}},{"text":"/ˈhæn.səm/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-us.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1648256","license":{"name":"BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"}}],"meanings":[{"partOfSpeech":"verb","definitions":[{"definition":"To render handsome.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"partOfSpeech":"adjective","definitions":[{"definition":"(of people, things, etc) Having a good appearance; good-looking.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"a handsome garment, house, tree, or horse"},{"definition":"Good, appealing, appropriate.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"Generous or noble in character.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Handsome is as handsome does."},{"definition":"Ample; moderately large.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"a handsome salary"},{"definition":"(said of things and people) Dexterous; skillful.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":["hefty","substantial","good-looking","pretty"],"antonyms":[]}],"license":{"name":"CC BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"},"sourceUrls":["https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handsome"]}]'''
```

Now...

```
import json

jlist = json.loads(js)

print(jlist[0]["meanings"])
```

However, if you've already processed the API response and have the data as shown in the question then it's just:

```
js = [{"word":"handsome","phonetic":"/ˈhæn.səm/","phonetics":[{"text":"/ˈhæn.səm/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-uk.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=9021972","license":{"name":"BY 3.0 US","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us"}},{"text":"/ˈhæn.səm/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/handsome-us.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1648256","license":{"name":"BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"}}],"meanings":[{"partOfSpeech":"verb","definitions":[{"definition":"To render handsome.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"partOfSpeech":"adjective","definitions":[{"definition":"(of people, things, etc) Having a good appearance; good-looking.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"a handsome garment, house, tree, or horse"},{"definition":"Good, appealing, appropriate.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"Generous or noble in character.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Handsome is as handsome does."},{"definition":"Ample; moderately large.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"a handsome salary"},{"definition":"(said of things and people) Dexterous; skillful.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":["hefty","substantial","good-looking","pretty"],"antonyms":[]}],"license":{"name":"CC BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"},"sourceUrls":["https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handsome"]}]

print(js[0]["meanings"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you received is a list, you can do this:

```py
print(type(data[0]))  # you have a dictionary now

# assign it to a variable
my_word = data[0] 

# Check the meanings 
print(my_word['meanings']) # this will print out your json
```